# Prove $\{a_n\}^r$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

For any $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, consider the sequence $\{a_n\}^r$ given by $a_n = r$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove $\{a_n\}^r$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I don't have any idea how to prove $\{a_n\}^r$ yet, but I do have an idea to show that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence. So far, I know that the difference between any two terms is equal to zero. Can we take $\epsilon = 0$ because the difference is zero? Does this mean that the sequence converges to zero? any idea or hints would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:** I don't know if this makes sense, but I will write down what I have in my mind.

Since the difference between any two terms is equal to zero, we have $|a_{i+1} - a_i| = 0 < \epsilon$. Thus, we can take $r = 0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{i+1} - a_i| < \epsilon$ for $i > k$. Therefore, $\{a_n\}$is a Cauchy sequence. Since $r = 0$, $\{a_n\}^r$ is a Cauchy sequence that converges to zero.

Comment: You don't take $\varepsilon$, it is given. You should start your proof like this: Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and then find a $N = N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is here, but you cannot prove that a sequence is Cauchy by showing only that the difference between consecutive terms is small. A sequence is Cauchy if, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\epsilon$ for every $n,m\geq N$. In your original situation, if $a_{n}=r$ for all $n$, then $a_{n}$ is a convergent (constant) sequence and it is a basic fact that every convergent sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: @JWP_HTX Sorry for my confusing post. I just don't know how to prove this, but I posted what I have in my mind.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes, I was going to write take $r = 0$, I got confused with my professor's definition.

Comment: No worries, you should either appeal to the basic fact about convergent sequences in my previous comment, or you can prove directly that your sequence is Cauchy using the definition that is given in both of the first two comments.

Comment: You can't take $r=0$ either. As the question is stated you should prove that this sequence is Cauchy for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: For completeness, for a counterexample to what @JWP_HTX already pointed out (difference of consecutive terms being small doesn't imply that the sequence is Cauchy) take $a_n = \ln(n)$ or more generally the partial sums of your favourite divergent series with general term that tends to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cauchy sequence is just a sequence where the values *eventually* get arbitrarily close to each other. Formally, we say that for an arbitrarily small value $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a “threshold” $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all indices $n, m \geq N$, the values $a_n$ and $a_m$ differ by no more than $\varepsilon$. This definition may seem daunting, but if you break it down, it should make sense. Following from this definition, here's how you would solve your problem:

1. Start by picking some arbitrary value of $\varepsilon$. Here, the word “arbitrary” indicates that $\varepsilon$ can be *anything*—notice that we aren't picking a specific value for $\varepsilon$ (as you did when you said “Can we take $\varepsilon = 0$ because the difference is zero?”).
2. Next, identify your “threshold” $N$. All values of your sequence past this threshold must be within a distance of $\varepsilon$ of each other. Usually, the tricky part is choosing the right value for $N$, but it shouldn't be too difficult for your problem.
3. Prove that for all indices $n, m \geq N$, the distance $|a_n - a_m| < \varepsilon$. This is to just verify that the threshold you picked in (2) is indeed valid.

And that's it! We have shown that for *arbitrarily small values of $\varepsilon$* (1), there is a *threshold $N$* (2) such that *all values past this threshold are $\varepsilon$-close to each other* (3). Almost every time you want to prove a sequence is Cauchy, you will follow these steps.

Comment: Thank you, this does help a lot. When I identify my N, should N be less or equal to $\epsilon$?

Comment: No. $N$ is a natural number number which tells you how far to go in the sequence before the property holds (in this case, it works for $N = 1$ since the elements of the sequence are equal). $\epsilon$ is a real number that is given to you that is arbitrarily small.

Comment: In particular, think of the proof like this.

(1) Someone gives you a really small (but positive) number $\epsilon$. (2) You get to choose $N$ based on that $\epsilon$ so that for every $n, m \geq N$, $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$. (3) They get to choose $n$ and $m$ and try to break your choice of $N$, but you specifically chose $N$ so that they can't break it. Thus the proof is done.

Comment: Thank you. Does the exponential matter when we consider the sequence?

Comment: @so0jong If by exponent you mean $r$, it shouldn't.